# Suppress an Exception but Continue after the Exception, not after the Suppression

Tags: python, exception

Assume the following minimal example:

```python
def external_code():
    for i in range(10):
        if i == 7:
            raise ValueError("I don't like sevens.")
        print(i)

external_code()
```

When suppressing the exception either through handling it

```python
try:
    external_code()
except ValueError:
    pass
```

or by suppression through `contextlib.suppress()`

```python
from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(ValueError):
    external_code()
```

the exception will not be raised, but the execution of the code after it will be prevented, and instead continue in the except block or after the suppression.

**Is it possible to suppress an Exception and then continue with the external code, as if the Exception would not even be there?** In the code examples above, this would cause all 10 numbers to be printed, instead of only 0 to 6.

I need this, because an external library (TensorFlow) raises an exception it should not raise. Related to the minimal example from above, this means that I cannot edit the code in the function, I can only put code around its call. I can comment out the exception in TensorFlow, but that's tedious with updating TF and would also cause the exception to not occur in other cases where it is actually appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could redefine the method at any time:

```
class SomeTensorFlowClass(object):
    def that_method(self, n=10):
        for i in range(n):
            if i == 7:
                raise ValueError()
            print(i)


stf = SomeTensorFlowClass()

def that_method(n=10):
    self = stf  # for non-static methods
    for i in range(n):
        print(i)

stf.that_method = that_method
```

This way, you still "update" TensorFlow, but you can undo it directly after the situation.

If you switch often, you can add a new flag like `seven_is_ok=False` to skip the Exception conditionally.

If you want to avoid copying library source code, you can [retrieve it from the live object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource) with `inspect.getsource(stf.that_method)` followed by the desired replacements and `exec("global that_method\n" + adapted_source_code)`. Be aware that indentation changes and forgotten imports may only mark the beginning of potentially many troubles with the inspect-based workaround.

Clearly, none of that is as beautiful as patching the library, but I assume you have reasons for not doing that now.